# Find all kids born on Friday

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

How I can find all dates in one table - which are Fridays - so that I can show the information in another table?

I am taking the information from `Ads.Date`.

Comment: SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2007-02-03');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [mysql function dayofweek()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

```
select * from ads where DayOfWeek(ads.Date)=6
```

dayofweek() returns weekdaynumber from 1-7 where 1 is Sunday. If you want to get everyone born on Friday you have to filter on dayofweek() = 6

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(birthday)=6
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it : 
`DATE_FORMAT( yourdate, '%w')` will return the day of the week, 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday. If you want all the fridays ou can try something like that :

```
SLECT DATE_FORMAT( yourdate, '%w') AS dateofbirth FROM yourtable WHERE dateofbirth = 5
```